# Vector not populating properly

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to figure out the average number of insertions before a collision occurs in a hash table of a specified size using the linear probing formula (h(k) = k%T where T is table size). I'm doing 100 "experiments" to calculate the average number of insertions before collision. Here is the code I have written to do that for just a table of size 23:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int sizeArray[7] = { 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 }; // ignore for now
    double resultArray[7] = { 0 }; // ignore for now
    vector<double> hashNumVec; // stores hash keys
    int hashValue = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double average;
    vector<double> resultVec;
    int randNum; 

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++){ // 100 experiments

        randNum = rand() % 100 + 1; // generate random number
        hashValue = (randNum) % 23; // hash value for T = 23


        vector<double>::iterator it;
        it = find(hashNumVec.begin(), hashNumVec.end(), hashValue);

        if (it == hashNumVec.end()){  //no collision

            count++;
            hashNumVec.push_back(hashValue);

        }
        else 
        {
            resultVec.push_back(count); // add the amount of insertions to vector
            break;
        }


    }


    for (auto i = resultVec.begin(); i != resultVec.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << ' ';


    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting my vector to populate with 100 values. Each of them will be the count value of how many insertions it took get to a collision. However when I print it out, it only shows that I have one value in the vector. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I am only trying to store how many insertions it takes to get to a collision each time. So lets say first time it takes 6 inserts before a collision and then it takes 5 inserts before a collision, takes 4 inserts before a collision.. and so on I want my vector to read `6 5 4 ...`

Answer (score 2):

That's because of that code:

```
    {
        resultVec.push_back(count); // add the amount of insertions to vector
        break;
    }
```

which breaks the `for` loop on the first detected collision. So you have only one value in `resultVec` which gets displayed.

**EDIT**

> I am expecting my vector to populate with 100 values.

The current code will not do it. You randomize and create a hash of 100 values. Then you store only the collision counter in the `resultVec` when the collision is detected. The probability to have 100 collision out of 100 randomization is 0.

Replace the `break;` with `count=0;`. It will print the number of insertions between collisions. In other words, how many insertion without the collisions were there before the next collision occurred.

**EDIT2**

In case you are looking for the number of insertions before the **first** collision then you need to replace the `break` with

```
count = 0;
hashNumVec.clear();
```

You need to clear the hash vector as well as the counter since after each collision you wish to start the measurement from the beginning (otherwise the counter will show the number of insertions before the second collision, then third and so on...)

Comment: How can I fix it? If I don't break, my Vector is filled with a lot of values that don't make sense.

Comment: I did that. My result vector now looks like `5 12 13 14 14 14 14 14 15 16 16 16 16 16 17 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 21 21 22 22 22 22 22 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23` which shouldn't be correct. The average number of inserts before collision for a table of that size should be around 6-8.

Comment: I tried your edit and the values are more like `8 2 3 1 3 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` so there should not be so many zeros.

Comment: I am only trying to store how many insertions it takes to get to a collision each time. So lets say first time it takes 6 inserts before a collision and then it takes 5 inserts before a collision, takes 4 inserts before a collision.. and so on I want my vector to read `6 5 4 ... `

Comment: @FlameDra Why not? If you get collision after the collision then you had 0 insertions between them. So looks like you have 77 collisions (if I counted correctly) and 23 insertions without collision (which makes sence because of `hashValue = (randNum) % 23;`).

Comment: If I want to average it then it ends up being 23/100 which is too small (almost 0). I'm supposed to get ~6-8 as my average.

Comment: @FlameDra Why? Maybe you are talking about the average number of insertions before the **first** collision? Because as more hash values you have the greater probability for another collision.

Comment: Yes that is what I want.

Comment: @FlameDra Please delete irrelevant comments not to confuse others.

Comment: I tried it and it seems to works. However my vector is smaller now. I am not getting 100 different values. Let me post the full question in an edit.

Comment: @FlameDra It is OK, since you save the counter on each collision. So you have 100 generations and 8-6 insertions before the collision so the result vector is expected to have from 100/6 (~17) to 100/8 (~8) items.

Comment: So when doing the average I will not divide by 100 right?

Comment: @FlameDra right. divide by the number of the stored values.

Comment: Does that make sense in context of the posted question prompt (Edit 2)

Comment: @FlameDra Yes. Definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Your program checks to see if a collision occurs within 100 insertions. It does not do 100 trials in which it counts how many insertions it takes to achieve a collision. To do that, you would need a secondary loop:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++){ // 100 experiments
    for(;;) {  // Each experiment continues until the "break" statement in your else clause.
        // The loop body, exactly as you currently have it written.
    }
    count = 0; // Reset for the next experiment!
}
```

Comment: I tried this and still get incorrect results in my vector like `5 12 13 14 14 14 14 14 15 16 16 16 16 16 17 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 21 21 22 22 22 22 22 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23`

Comment: You initialized `count` outside of the loop. You need to either declare it locally to the loop, or reset it to 0 after each experiment.

Comment: Check my comment on the other guy. Also my Edit to the main post.

Comment: Is `hashVec` supposed to be empty at the start of each experiment? In your current implementation, it retains the data that was inserted in previous experiments, so that in experiment 99 it'll be fuller than it was in experiment 0. By moving the declaration of `hashNumVec` and `hashValue` to inside the outer `for` loop, I get a vector like this: `7 3 7 5 3 4 5 3 11 2 9 11 7 8 5 3 8 7 2 3 9 4 10 6 6 8 5 5 2 4 10 3 7 2 9 1 6 5 8 9 2 3 1 10 7 9 6 12 5 3 6 6 6 8 2 3 5 11 10 5 6 13 5 3 2 4 9 8 6 6 5 6 3 4 6 6 10 6 13 4 5 6 4 1 1 2 7 2 4 5 6 1 4 3 4 15 1 5 7 6`